# Question regarding Zxing for Android

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

working with Zxing in J2ME i had:

```
MonochromeBitmapSource source = new LCDUIImageMonochromeBitmapSource(bitmapFile);
```

I'm having no troubles working with it Zxing in Android except in this case, i don't know how to create the MonochromeBitmapSource given that there is no LCDUI.... class.

Any hint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find `PlanarYUVLuminanceSource` in the `android/` module. This is the counterpart for Android.